docker login failed to Sonatype Nexus
There is a remote docker repository on nexus.connex.ro:8063.
I want to skip certificate validation so I have added the repository as  "insecure-registries".
Unfortunately when I try to login it still complains  tls: failed to verify certificate:
This is my /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["nexus.connex.ro:8063"]
}

The remote repository use a self singed certificate. I have tried to save the cert into a file and put it into the /etc/docker/certs.d/nexus.connect.ro/ folder as a .crt file, but nothing changed.
This is the error message what I got:
Error response from daemon: Get "https://nexus.connex.ro:8063/v2/": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs instead

Any advise how to fix?

Finally I was able to find what is the issue. Despite of I have "insecure-repositories" in my /etc/docker/daemon.json my docker service did not pick it up.
docker info command indicate this becasue only 127.0.0.0/8 was under the Insecure Registries:
Why?
Becasue it was installed by snap!
This installation have other daemon.json in /snap/docker/2963/config/daemon.json  and of course this have no insecure settings.
Editing the proper daemon.json fixed the issue.
